# Importing numbers with leading zeros as text strings in gnumeric

Tags: spreadsheet, import, gnumeric

I have a csv file with numbers, some that start with zeros. Those zeros are somewhat important to me. All the entries in the file are encapsulated with double quotes. Gnumeric's import dialogue recognises `"` as the text indicator. The preview pane looks great; all my leading zeros are there where they should be ... yet when it imports, they're all are gone. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Just remembered that I don't have to format as text; it's possible to display as many leading zeros on a number as you want by specifying a custom format, eg for 8 digits the custom format is `00000000`. This way you don't have to turn it into text. Hope this helps someone else in this situation.